# iOS WatchKit handleWatchKitExtensionRequest not firing until app is launched for first time after downloading app to watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

PLATFORM AND VERSION: iOS 8.3 on Xcode 6.3

DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM

The app is unresponsive to Apple Watch button press ONLY after just installing a fresh build onto phone AND watch. We want to understand why the watch doesn't communicate properly with the phone until the first time the phone app is launched after a fresh install to both. Everything seems great otherwise. Works fine after backgrounding, foregrounding, terminating the app on the phone, restarting the phone...you name it. Just this first time.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE

1. Install a fresh build on the iPhone
2. switch to apple watch app on iPhone to install the Watch Extension app for the watch
3. Install the watch app (Do not switch back to the parent app on the iPhone)
4. press button that fires openParentApplication:reply: (can press multiple times with no affect on parent)
5. Open the parent app on the iPhone
6. After you do this, a flood of messages is sent to handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply: in the app delegate on the parent app from the watch (all of the button presses you did on step 4)
7. From then on, everything works fine

Comment: This is usually my first question when encountering issues with openParentApplication. Are you performing all of your work in handleWatchKitRequest in a background task?

Comment: I would imagine it's running on the main thread since I'm not specifying a thread to run on plus all of the visuals work every time (which generally doesn't if not run on the main thread). It's only in the specific situation that things don't work as expected.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if this is an Apple bug. Since I've noticed a couple other apps currently on the Apple Watch that seem to be experiencing the same issue, that is that the watch app doesn't process anything until the main app is opened at least once after the watch app has been downloaded.

Comment: Perhaps. I've never had an issue, for what it's worth. You're not relying on any data or values that are only set up once you run the iOS app?

Comment: No... and to reiterate the actual time stamp for the calls going to the parent app from the watch distinctly show that the Apple stock method "handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:" does not get called until the parent app is opened. I have tested this many times and have waited a significant amount of time before opening up the parent app after initially sending the watch messages.

Comment: Is it possible this bug is happening because I'm using the openParentApplication method instead of using a framework which was required for 8.2 and optional for 8.3?

Comment: For what it's worth, I am experiencing the same issue. And, to @bgilham's point, I am executing my code in a background task. From what I can tell, none of the code in the AppDelegate is ever called if the app is in a terminated state. It is almost as if the app is never launched.